# Points extruded in object mode but not edit mode how do I get rid of these lines

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging

[image]

For some reason there are extruded lines and points when I am in object mode on the model's left shoulder, but these lines do not show up in edit mode. I thought it might be the weighted paint but it doesn't seem the case. How do I reduce/get rid of these lines.

Comment: do the bones of the armature look the same in edit mode and in pose mode?

Answer (score 1):

I seemed to have overlapped my points and duplicated them during edit mode and making them deformed in object mode.

Answer (score 0):

you have hidden geometry , in edit mode press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Select the mesh

Go into edit mode

<kbd>A</kbd> to select all

then go into the (t)tool shelf-->tools-->remove-->remove doubles